InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error Incompatible shapes: [32,800,64] vs. [32,125,64] in PatchEncoder in ViT
I am building a 3D ViT for classification
class PatchEncoder(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_patches, projection_dim, **kwargs):
        super(PatchEncoder, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.num_patches = num_patches
        self.projection_dim = projection_dim
        self.projection = layers.Dense(units=projection_dim)
        self.position_embedding = self.add_weight(
            name="position_embedding",
            shape=(num_patches, projection_dim),  # Remove the first dimension
            initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=0.02),
            trainable=True
        )

    def call(self, patches):
        batch_size = tf.shape(patches)[0]
        positions = tf.range(start=0, limit=self.num_patches, delta=1)
        positions_embedding = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.position_embedding, positions)
        positions_embedding = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(positions_embedding, axis=0), [batch_size, 1, 1])

        projected_patches = self.projection(patches)
        encoded_patches = projected_patches + positions_embedding

        print(f"PatchEncoder: patches shape={patches.shape}, encoded_patches shape={encoded_patches.shape}")
        
        return encoded_patches


class Patches3D(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, patch_size, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.patch_size = patch_size

    def call(self, volumes):
        batch_size = tf.shape(volumes)[0]
        depth = volumes.shape[1]
        height = volumes.shape[2]
        width = volumes.shape[3]
        channels = volumes.shape[4]

        patches = tf.image.extract_patches(
            images=tf.reshape(volumes, [-1, height, width, channels]),
            sizes=[1, self.patch_size, self.patch_size, 1],
            strides=[1, self.patch_size, self.patch_size, 1],
            rates=[1, 1, 1, 1],
            padding='VALID'
        )

        patch_depth = depth // self.patch_size
        patch_height = height // self.patch_size
        patch_width = width // self.patch_size

        patches = tf.reshape(patches, [batch_size, patch_depth, patch_height, patch_width, -1])
        patches = tf.transpose(patches, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
        patches = tf.reshape(patches, [batch_size, -1, self.patch_size * self.patch_size * channels])

        print(f"Patches3D: volumes shape={volumes.shape}, patches shape={patches.shape}")

        return patches

# Assuming x_train has the shape (1265, 32, 32, 32, 1)
x_train_expanded = tf.expand_dims(x_train, axis=-1)

# Now create the ViT classifier
def create_vit_classifier(input_shape=(32, 32, 32, 1), num_classes=1):
    patch_size = 6
    num_patches = (input_shape[0] // patch_size) * (input_shape[1] // patch_size) * (input_shape[2] // patch_size)
    projection_dim = 64
    transformer_layers = 8

    inputs = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
    # Augment data.
    augmented = data_augmentation(inputs)
    # Create patches.
    patches = Patches3D(patch_size)(augmented)
    # Encode patches.
    encoded_patches = PatchEncoder(num_patches, projection_dim)(patches)

    print(f"create_vit_classifier: input shape={input_shape}, patches shape={patches.shape}, encoded_patches shape={encoded_patches.shape}")

    for _ in range(transformer_layers):
        encoded_patches = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(encoded_patches)
        attention_output = layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=4, key_dim=projection_dim, dropout=0.1)(encoded_patches, encoded_patches)
        attention_output = layers.Dropout(0.1)(attention_output)
        encoded_patches = layers.Add()([encoded_patches, attention_output])

        feedforward_output = layers.Dense(projection_dim, activation=tf.nn.gelu)(encoded_patches)
        feedforward_output = layers.Dropout(0.1)(feedforward_output)
        encoded_patches = layers.Add()([encoded_patches, feedforward_output])

    representation = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)(encoded_patches)
    representation = layers.Flatten()(representation)
    representation = layers.Dropout(0.1)(representation)
    outputs = layers.Dense(units=num_classes, activation='sigmoid')(representation)
    
    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    return model

vit_classifier = create_vit_classifier(input_shape=(32, 32, 32, 1))
vit_classifier.summary()
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers.legacy import Adam
vit_classifier.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),  # Adjust loss function as needed
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()]  # Adjust metrics as needed
)

# Train the model
history = vit_classifier.fit(
    x_train, y_train,
    batch_size=32,
    epochs=10,
    validation_split=0.2
)

And I get following error:
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[143], line 108
    101 vit_classifier.compile(
    102     optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    103     loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),  # Adjust loss function as needed
    104     metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()]  # Adjust metrics as needed
    105 )
    107 # Train the model
--> 108 history = vit_classifier.fit(
    109     x_train, y_train,
    110     batch_size=32,
    111     epochs=10,
    112     validation_split=0.2
    113 )

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:122, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    119     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    120     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    121     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 122     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    123 finally:
    124     del filtered_tb

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py:53, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     51 try:
     52   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 53   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     54                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     55 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     56   if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node gradient_tape/functional_107_1/patch_encoder_61_1/add/BroadcastGradientArgs defined at (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main


in train_step

Incompatible shapes: [32,800,64] vs. [32,125,64]
     [[{{node gradient_tape/functional_107_1/patch_encoder_61_1/add/BroadcastGradientArgs}}]] [Op:__inference_one_step_on_iterator_834044]

I understand that there is some issue when applying the gradient and I have a mismatch, which I think comes from the PatchEncoder. But I cant pinpoint the issue:
What causes this error?
Thank you for reading, Luca
I tried fixing the Encoder but somehow that didn't help. It even goes through the first epoch, which is weird in my eyes. I also thought that it could be in pulling out the patches but it doesn't seem to be an issue.
